# I am trying to post <div> content to database using jquery $.post()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want add  data to table using jquery $.post() method..but its not updating.
HTML:this is html code

```
    <div id="ant-container" name="text" style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC;height:300px;width:80%;">
    <?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])&& $_POST['text'] ==''){
    echo parseWord($myFile);
    }elseif (isset($_POST['text'])) { echo $_POST['text'];}
    </div>
```

jquery:this jquery code

```
 var div_contents = $('#ant-container').html();
    var ides = $('#id').val();
    $.post("content.php", { contents:div_contents, id :ides});
```

In this i am getting both "ides" as well as "div_contents" 
PHP:This my php code(content.php)

```
$div = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contents']); 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']); 
$sql ="UPDATE `antr_essay` SET `annotext`=      {$div},`grade`='$_POST[grade]',`comments`='$_POST[comments]'
WHERE id=$id";
$update=$DB->update($sql);
$sql ="UPDATE `antr_essay` 
   SET `annotext`={$div},
   `grade`='$_POST[grade]',
    `comments`='$_POST[comments]'
        WHERE id=$id";
   $update=$DB->update($sql);
      //var_dump($sql);exit;
if (isset($update)){
  echo  '<div align="center" class="alert alert-success">';
  echo "Annotation added Successfully";
  echo '</div>';
}
header("loction:annotate.php");
```

I after submitting its not redirecting to content.php and table is not updating.
What can id do pls help me

Thanks,

Comment: Where you **POST**ing the fields grade and comments used in the SQL Query?

Comment: In same table but those value come from other fields..those values are coming but only <div> content is not coming

Comment: hmm..I'm speaking about it as the call to $.post doesn't seems to set it. But..ok. :)

Comment: Means you cannot update only one field using $.post()

Answer (score 1):

Please check the spelling of location you have given in header().

Change

```
header("loction:annotate.php");
```

To

```
header("location:annotate.php");
```

Comment: Changed but still table is not updating

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/):

```
var div = $("#ant-container").serializeArray();
$.post("content.php", div );
```

Comment: Thanks..will try get back to you

Comment: $.post("content.php", { contents:div});syntax should be like this know

Comment: Yeah! It should be like that!

Comment: Works for me. It can be accessed as: `$_POST["input_name"];`

Comment: Really!but how can you set input type and name in <div>,suppose if i give <div name="text" id="#ant-container">..will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put that div into another div and try like this

```
    <div id="my_div"><div id="ant-container" name="text" style="border:1px solid #CCCCCC;height:300px;width:80%;"></div></div>
```

Then get the content of "my_div" as

```
var div_contents = $('#my_div').html();
var ides = $('#id').val();
$.post("content.php", { contents:div_contents, id :ides});
```

and try to correct the spelling of **location**

```
header("location:annotate.php");
```

Better to use **ajax**  like

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "content.php", 
           data : { 'contents':div_contents, 'id' :ides},
           success: function(result) 
           {     
                alert(result);
           }
});
```

Comment: Thanks,i will try it.i changed the spelling to location

Comment: can u alert the div_contents..??and tell me what you got

Comment: yeah..there the value is coming..but when i var_dump($_POST) in content.php its not showing any value..it means the data is not posting..in content.php page right?

Comment: Absolutly....I think id is not getting for u....may check for your id value before posting..

Comment: id ans div_contents both are coming but these values are not coming in content.php when checked by var_dump($_POST)

Comment: Why dont you try with ajax in that case..??

Comment: can you please help how can i use ajax for this

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion You have some sql error:

```
$sql ="UPDATE `antr_essay` SET `annotext`=      {$div},`grade`='$_POST[grade]',`comments`='$_POST[comments]' -> like below .
WHERE id=$id";
$update=$DB->update($sql);
$sql ="UPDATE `antr_essay` 
   SET `annotext`={$div}, -> **this line why not SET `annotext`='{div}'** ?
   `grade`='$_POST[grade]',
    `comments`='$_POST[comments]'
        WHERE id=$id";
   $update=$DB->update($sql);
```

Comment: The $.post() is not at all sending data to this page(content.php)..so its difficult to check sql-error

Comment: I have marked down the bad places. **this line .... ** ? You can correct this places and check if work. For handlings sql-errors you can do sth like `if (!$update) {header("HTTP/1.1 400 SQl Error"); echo $errors; exit();}`

Comment: Of course after that you must extend your $.post to sth like this: `$.post("content.php", { contents:div_contents, id :ides}).fail(fumction(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(jqXHR.responseText); })`

Comment: @Mallu have you change both lines ? The first one too ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would bugshoot this:

1) Make a version of the page the AJAX calls with a test query that you can run to make sure that part is doing what you expect it to. Suggest simply accesing this page via a browser, not AJAX until you know it works. As others have said, it could be that it's simply failing because you are trying to send php headers after an echo, or SQL errors, or typos etc.

2) Make another test page that just delivers the responses you are expecting AJAX to handle. Suggest just getting the DIV content POST-ing across and echoing back.

Once you have the two working as expected you just need to combine them. Take it step by step and if it fails at some point, you will have a better idea of the cause.

Finally, you don't seem to have any facility for handling SQL errors - suggest you add some so you'll know if that is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

use `<script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>` for connectiong to jquery and also try below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var div_contents = $('#ant-container').html();
        var ides = $('#id').val();
        $.post("content.php", { contents:div_contents, id :ides});
    });
</script>
```